# Finding the index of an object in an array using one of that object's properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have a `NSMutableArray` `pages` with several objects (instances of `Page`). Each `Page` instance has a UUID and other properties, such as contents. When a `page` changes, everything may change except the UUID. After a change, I would like to find out the index of a particular `Page` in `pages` by using `indexOfObject:`. I use the UUID to identify the index I'm looking for and this works just fine:

```
NSMutableArray *uuids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [self.pages count]; i++) {
    [uuids addObject:[[pages objectAtIndex:i] uuid]];
}

NSUInteger indexOfPage = [uuids indexOfObject:page.uuid];
```

Now my question is if there is a more elegant way to do this. All I really need is the index of the `Page` object in `pages` that has a given UUID.

There is 
`- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate` or `indexOfAccessibilityElement:<#(id)#>` but I'm not really sure how either of these could help me out with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass the `isEqual:` method in `Page` as follows:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual: (Page *) otherPage
{
    if (![otherPage isKindOfClass:[Page class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self.UUID isEqualToString: otherPage.UUID];
}
```

Then `indexOfObject:` will work correctly.

From [Apple's NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> Starting at index 0, each element of the array is sent an isEqual:
>   message until a match is found or the end of the array is reached.
>   This method passes the anObject parameter to each isEqual: message.
>   Objects are considered equal if isEqual: (declared in the NSObject
>   protocol) returns YES.

Answer (score 2):

From NSArray docs:

> each element of the array is sent an `isEqual:` message until a match is found or the end of the array is reached.

So you can override `isEqual:` so that it returns `YES` if the two pages has the same UUID.

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[Page class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    Page *otherPage = object;
    return [self.uuid isEqualToString:otherPage.uuid];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hejazi. Just wondering if I really need the isKindOfClass. I've implemented Ahsley's and it works just fine, but perhaps yours is the correct and saver answer. Can you explain why you are checking isKindOfClass?

Comment: Just in case. So that when I'm accessing `uuid` I know it's there and I'm not comparing with an object from another class.

Answer (score 0):

May be this way by using a predicate, assuming pages is your array of all pages:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(UUID == %@)", searchUUID]];
filteredArray = [pages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

And once you have the object, which should be at objectAtIndex:0 in the filtered array assuming your uuid is unique, you could ask the index of that object:

NSUInteger indexOfPage = [pages indexOfObject:theObject];